# Newbie with barycentric coordinates: why one is zero when on a vertex?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

I'm trying to calculate if a 2D point lies inside a triangle and I solved the following system:

```
| X_source |                 | x_first_vertex, x_second_vertex, x_third_vertex |
| Y_source | = [b0,b1,b2] *  | y_first_vertex, y_second_vertex, y_third_vertex |
```

where b0,b1 and b2 are the barycentric coordinates I was searching for.

Now I'm wondering why, if the barycentric coordinates in wikipedia's picture here ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TriangleBarycentricCoordinates.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTriangleBarycentricCoordinates.svg)) have a 1 component when lying on a vertex, am I getting 0 for one of b0,b1,b2 when the vertex lies on an edge/vertex of the triangle..

The first vertex I obtained is: [ 0; 0.00000...17; 0.0500], and since it almost lies on the first vertex.. how come these three values don't yield 1 if I sum them together?

Where am I getting wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve a little bit different system. Barycentric coordinates has to sum to the one. So you simply augment your system with one more equation

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_s \\
y_s \\
1 
\end{matrix}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
1 & 1 & 1  
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
b_0 \\
b_1 \\
b_3  
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Your original system is $2\times 3$. You cannot expect unique solution with such a system, that is the reason why you didn't get one when you summed $b_i$.